# How to install 3rd party dependencies (like Alamofire) in a playground

Tags: swift-playground

I am new to Swift, Playground and Xcode. I am starting my first project and if everything is ok on the Xcode part, I am having difficulties importing 3rd party dependencies in playground. I have been googling for the last few days but unable to find a solution on how to install/import a pod in a playground. I would appreciate if someone can tell me how to do that or direct me to the right tool, doc set that explains it.

Comment: http://unsure.org/swift-playgrounds-and-dependencies/    this may be help you

Comment: Thanks Ram. I knew this post. I have tested it. It doesn't  work. Wrote to the developper. Told me it was outdated with no update.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Xcode project, install there all the dependencies you need and then add playground file(New file-> Playground). You will be able to import 3rd party stuff.

Comment: Thanks Vitaly, I did that several times. I also found on the Cocoapods site that you must create a workspace then add a project and install your dependencies then create a Playground. No chance, I still get an error when importing any depen

Comment: ooops pressed the wrong key. ....  dependencies. I must be doing something wrong, but I am stuck with this issue for several days now. Have you done it on your side? Is it working?

Comment: after you've imported all your dependencies you need to build the project, then it is possible to import in playground

Comment: Cool, if you want to work with alamofire, add to playground this:
import XCPlayground 
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

Answer (score 0):

You can create a playground with any number of 3rd party libraries with [Arena](https://github.com/finestructure/Arena):

```
arena https://github.com/finestructure/Gala
  resolving package dependencies
  libraries found: Gala
✅  created project in folder 'SPM-Playground'
```